# Read xml custom prolog(Processing Instruction) using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

How to read the custom prolog in XML using XSLT transformation?

In my application, some of the messages arrive with the custom prolog with special instructions on how to handle incoming message. I need to read those labels and process/route the message accordingly. I already have a working xslt to read the  element, but need one to read label prolog.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?Label 12345678|JSON|LABEL2?>
<order>
  ...
</order>
```

Output:

```
CustomerId: 12345678
Output type: JSON
Other label: LABEL2
```

Comment: Well, you can select `/processing-instruction('label')` to get that node, its string value then will be `12345678|JSON|LABEL2`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you refer to as a "custom prolog" is actually a processing-instruction child of the document node, so it is accessible as `/processing-instruction()` (for all PIs), or `/processing-instruction(Label)` for one with a specific name. The target of the PI ("Label") is available as the result of the name() function applied to this node, the string value (`12345678|JSON|LABEL2`) is available via the string() function, or implicitly in operations such as "=" that extract the string value.

Comment: Thanks @Michael, adding the code block for anyone who come across this question in future.<xsl:template match="processing-instruction('Label')">
  <Label>
   <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </Label>
 </xsl:template>

Comment: Note that you need quotes around 'Label'.

Comment: You need the quotes in XPath 1.0 but not in 2.0. The question does say 1.0, but it's about 20 years since I used 1.0 so one forgets the details.